# run a python script to create my schema on Amazon RDS DB instance

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy

I have a Python script that uses sqlalchemy to create a MySQL schema.

Today I launched an Amazon RDS DB and successfully logged in, staring at a blinking cursor

```
mysql>
```

At this point, I realized I had no schema. The schema I want to use was written by someone else and it lives in a Python script.

Python is not installed; nor do I believe it should be. I simply have a MySQL database, yet no way to implement the tables.

How can I execute a Python script while on my AWS RDB, or is there some other way to go about this?

Comment: With the right permissions you can deploy the schema remotely. You can use another instance in AWS EC2 to run the python script. Just make sure you have the right connection details.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your issue is easily and intuitively solved with a slight conceptual shift on your part.

Ask yourself this:

*Just now, which computer was I connected to when I saw the `$` or `C:\>` or some other shell prompt? Which computer is the one where I was connected immediately before I saw the `mysql>` prompt?*

Now, contrast that to the answer you would have given to the same question, if you were *not* using RDS?  (I'll call this a "conventional" setup.)

In the latter question, the answer might be "the MySQL server," but in the former question, whichever machine it may be, the answer can't be "the MySQL server."  You had to be somewhere else.

So, it seems like you are dealing with two different scenarios, but that isn't true.  In actuality, in the conventional setup, the fact that you may be "on" the server is not really important, because programs and scripts that interact with MySQL may be running on the same machine, but they are still making a connection *to* the MySQL server process and operating at arm's length.  People often run scripts (or their web server, etc.) on the server itself, assuming this has meaning, but it doesn't.

The place where you run the script is the computer you're using before connecting to MySQL... whether it's your laptop or an EC2 instance, or whatever.  The script just needs to be connected to the MySQL server with the appropriate hostname, username, and password, when it runs from wherever it is running, whatever machine that happens to be.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT 2:

Going to a MySQL shell prompt and launching a Python script from there is, AFAIK, not possible.